# How do you use a python2 module inside a python3 program

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've written a 40k line program in python3. Now I need to use a module throughout my program that is called pytan which will impart a functionality addition. The problem is that pytan is written in python2.

So is it possible to switch the interpreter to python 2.7 inside one script that is called by another running in python 3?

What's the best way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot "switch the interpreter to python 2.7".  You're either using one or the other.  Your choices are effectively:

- Come up with an alternative that doesn't require the `pytan` module.
- Modify the `pytan` module so that it runs under Python 3.
- Modify *your* code so that it runs under Python 2.
- Isolate the code that requires `pytan` such that you can run it as a subprocess under the python 2 interpreter. There are a number of problems with this solution:

  - It requires people to have two versions of Python installed.
  - It will complicate things like syntax highlighting in your editor.
  - It will complicate testing.
  - It may require some form of IPC (pipes, sockets, files, etc...) between your main code and your python 2 subprocess (this isn't terrible, but it's a chunk of additional complexity that wouldn't be necessary if you could make one of the other options work).

Comment: Incidentally, if you're talking about [this pytan module](https://github.com/tanium/pytan), a quick glance suggests that it has been written with support for python 3 in mind. Are you sure about the python 2 requirements? The repository has had some recent activity, so possibly questions or contributions there would be a good path forward.

Comment: #1 is probably the most desirable for *this* project; #2 is the most desirable for the ecosystem as a whole. I'd probably swap #3 and #4; 3 sounds easier, but is more of a bandaid than 4.

Comment: I have a direct line with the developer, I intend to ask him about python 3 support, perhaps they are starting the conversion now. This pytan module is just some kinda SOAP interface used to communicate with the Tanium security application, so maybe I could so it without pytan. Thanks, all good advice and info... now I just need to do some more research and make the decision.